# Avoiding .NET MVC controller calls with angular-ui-router

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building a .NET MVC 5 application on back-end and Angularjs on front-end.
I am loading `.cshtml` views in a div `containerOne` on a parent `.cshtml` page with `ui.router` and everything is working fine. An issue I would like to solve is when I enter manually a page URL that is C# controller's action path(in the example I provided below it is `/Proposal/Customers`) - my view is loaded on a whole page. What I want to be called is a `.state` named `'customers'` in my example, or something like that. My example code is(part of my `proposalConfig.js`):

```
.state('customers', {   
    url: 'AllCustomers',
    views: {
        containerOne": {
            templateUrl: '/Proposal/Customers'
        }
    }
});
```

On my back-end I have a `ProposalController.cs` and an action method `Customers` that calls a `Customers.cshtml` view.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

EDIT

The same thing happens if, instead of `'AllCustomers'` I put `'/Proposal/Customers'`, and then after the first load of a `.state` I refresh a page.

I forgot to mention that I have  `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode(true);` in a `proposalConfig.js` file.

Comment: Are you using partial views and returning `PartialView` results from your actions?

Comment: @Jasen No, a regular `View()`

Comment: can you clarify what your issue is. "my view is loaded on a whole page".

Comment: It's a routing issue. Normally the server would handle the routing. Here angular handles the routes and makes the request. But if you directly enter the url you skip the angular app and get the raw template.

Comment: @Jasen is there a way to avoid skipping angular routing? To somehow make angular to handle all requests?

Comment: @jw56578 I mean that `Customers.cshtml` is not shown as a partial view loaded on a `div` of a parent view, but it is the only view showing on the page.

Comment: I'm still looking for a good solution myself

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the entire page html markup (html tag, body tag and such)is being returned when you only want the specific content of the Customer.cshtml, which I also assume only has what you want in it,  its probably because your view has a shared view start layout. Put this in Customer.cshtml

```
   @{
    Layout = null ;
}
```

Comment: I already have `Layout = null;`. And I want to show all content of Customer.cshtml, but within a `containerOne` div on a parent view, not on a separate page.